# Apache HTTPClient giving connection refused exception

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to create a rest client which posts an xml string and retreives an xml response.But when i try it using the below code ,i am getting the issue connection refused.Also when i hit my mock url using postman addon in chrome i am getting the xml response.Kindly help me out in figuring out why the issue is occuring and how i should be solving this

### My Code

```
public String testMockWS(String inputString) throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException{
    //String inputStr =  "";

    String postURL = "https://demo0667044.mockable.io/testXMLRestWS";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postURL);

    try{
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputString);
        input.setContentType("text/xml");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);   
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch(Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

in which input string is the xml input i want to post.The error i am getting is given below :

### Error

```
2019-02-07 10:23:01 DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:158 - Get connection for route {}->http://demo0667044.mockable.io
2019-02-07 10:23:01 DEBUG DefaultClientConnectionOperator:174 - Connecting to demo0667044.mockable.io:80
2019-02-07 10:23:02 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:176 - Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@23ceabc1 closed
2019-02-07 10:23:02 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:160 - Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@23ceabc1 shut down
2019-02-07 10:23:02 DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:196 - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@5d5eef3d
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connectOutput : 
 null

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.util.TestJavaFile.testMockWS(TestJavaFile.java:128)
    at com.util.TestJavaFile.main(TestJavaFile.java:57)
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue and get the response.I have also tried putting accept trust strategy thinking it might be SSL issue .But that also did not work out.Kindly help me out getting response back.

Comment: Connection Refused error comes when the listener is not running on the server.  Just try testing it with simple telnet. `telnet demo0667044.mockable.io 80`

Comment: Check if the server is really listening on host demo0667044.mockable.io port 443.

Comment: i cannot connect through telnet.But when i try using postman to send a rest call i am getting back the response

Comment: Do you connect to the server via a proxy?

Comment: from postman.Yes i connect via proxy which is configured in IE.From Code i dont set any proxy

Comment: Then that's the problem. You simply canno't reach the server when not going via the proxy.

Comment: I have tried setting proxy using the code    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1",8080);
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);.But i am getting error "HTTP error code : 401"

Comment: So either the proxy or the server requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(192.168..., Integer.parseInt(80));
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
```